# Ruby on Rails: "undefined method 'address='" when run spec with Factory Bot and Geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to run a spec that creates a list of models (configured in a factory) that contains a method called address, which is used by the Geocoder gem, to encapsulate the address fields.

When running, the error appears:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `address=' for #<BusinessEstablishment:0x000055fea90c0c08>

Did you mean?  address
```

I couldn't find a solution.

My model:

```
class BusinessEstablishment < ApplicationRecord
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
  after_validation :reverse_geocode

  def get_establishment_by_current_location(location)
    BusinessEstablishment.near([location[:latitude], location[:longitude]], 5, units: :km)
  end

  def address
    [street, number, neighborhood, zip_code, city_ibge_code, city, latitude, longitude].compact.join(', ')
  end
end
```

My factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :business_establishment, class: 'BusinessEstablishment' do
    cnpj { Faker::IDNumber.brazilian_citizen_number }
    company_name { Faker::Company.name }
    trade_name { Faker::Company.suffix }
    phone { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
    street { Faker::Address.street_name }
    number { Faker::Address.building_number }
    neighborhood { Faker::Address.community }
    zip_code { Faker::Address.zip_code }
    city_ibge_code { Faker::Address.city_suffix }
    city { Faker::Address.city }
    state { Faker::Address.state }
    latitude { Faker::Address.latitude }
    longitude { Faker::Address.longitude }
  end
end
```

My spec:

```
describe 'GET /v1/search_prices/products/prices' do
  subject(:get_prices) do
    get '/v1/search_prices/products/prices',
        params: params
  end

  let!(:business_establishment) { create_list(:business_establishment, 20) }

  context 'when searches prices' do
    it 'returns all prices' do
      get_prices
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Geocoder doesn't provide an `address` attribute (eg a setter). https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geocoding-objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["undefined method \`address=' for" error using geocoder gem in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590814/undefined-method-address-for-error-using-geocoder-gem-in-rails)